# PayPal OAuth2 REST API Basics

Tags: api, rest, paypal, oauth-2.0

Im trying out the new PayPal REST API and Im wanting to learn how to use it using PHP / curl.

I am new to using curl so please forgive...

From the paypal developers documentation I gather the required fields and I put together the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$postDataArray = array("grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postDataArray);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
$headerArray = array('Accept: application/json','Accept-Language: en_US');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArray);
$clientID_Secret = "clientID:secret";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientID_Secret);
```

the next few lines i added due to googling.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

This returns nothing.
Please help.

Comment: Here you need to make sure the clientID and secret are the values not string literals: $clientID_Secret = "clientID:secret";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a sample: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-curlsamples/blob/master/execute_all_calls.php

copying the curl specific code:

```
$curl = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId . ":" . $clientSecret);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you. Now im off to learn how to push a credit card transaction to this REST method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working. But you have to change this $postDataArray = array("grant_type=client_credentials"); to $postDataArray = "grant_type=client_credentials";. Need to remove the array type;